# Sequelize (v1.5) and node

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How can I check whether a field exists in my table, via sequelize orm.
Note that I have already defined the full object model. I just need to check whether a particular field exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what is inside your database via:

```
sequelize.getQueryInterface().describeTable('nameOfTableHere').success(function(data){})
```

If you want to check the table of a specific model you could also do this:

```
sequelize.getQueryInterface().describeTable(Model.tableName).success(function(data) {})
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives the structure of the table.

Comment: And with that you can check if the relevant attribute/field is in that structure?

Comment: Yeah, if I have to check for fields directly in the table, then this will do the task.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had already defined the object model, the following expression gives an array of field names defined in the model.

```
Object.keys(Model.rawAttributes)
```

Comment: Ah. :) I thought you want to make sure that a specific field is in the db which is probably not defined by your schema.

Comment: Yeah... this is probably not the answer people are here for.